# Need MAMP to use (an older version of) Python

Tags: python, macos, mamp

One of my sites requires python and cherrypy. Locally, I need to get all of this running with MAMP. I have the site running in MAMP with the exception of features reliant on Python. I need to run python 2.5. My OS version is 2.7.

How do I set this up? I seem to have 2.5 installed in addition to 2.7 and 2.6

```
which python
/usr/bin/python

which python2.5
/usr/bin/python2.5
```

but the usr/bin/python2.5 is an alias to: System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5

How do I make python2.5 available to MAMP without screwing up the vers OSX needs?

It's a drupal site, MAMP is handling everything php related, and perhaps I wrongfully assumed it needed to have anything to do with the python scripts of the site. As I read more about cherrypy, it seems cherrypy serves the python scripts, and I do have cherrypy running (localhost:8080 test works anyway), so perhaps all I need to do is make sure python2.5 is being used instead of the default? (2.7)

Comment: you mean to use php exec function? or to run cgi type scripts? I think if you have to use mamp you need to look at WSGI alternatively f you dont need php you can just use the server that comes with cherrypy ...
but im not totally sure i understand your question

Comment: sorry I'll try to be more clear! So I definitely need PHP because this is a drupal site, but there's a core feature that relies on python and cherrypy.  I have cherrypy running (localhost:8080 works, anyway), so perhaps I'm wrong from the start in thinking MAMP needs to have anything to do with the python scripts in this site?

Comment: How does your PHP or Drupal code invoke cherrypy?

Comment: - a rewrite rule in htaccess, from what I see. Requests to ^ip/(.*) are forwarded to cherrypy @ 127.0.0.1:8081

So I see now that I've checked this, I should be setting my local cherrypy port to 8081 instead of (what seems like the default) 8080, somehow. Thanks for the responses by the way!

Comment: just invoke it as 
python25 {start_server}.py rather than {python start_server}.py
then send your requests from drupal to the proper cherrypy port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea.  You definitely want to leave the OS python version alone.  Or you could be breaking multiple dependencies.  We launch our cherrypy instances in our rc.local script at boot.  This is where you specify which version of python to use when executing your cherrypy app.

Our rc.local script looks like this:

```
/opt/Python-3.2/python /var/www/html/appname/webapp.py > stdout.log &
```